# Exclude item from value_counts over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following dataframe:

```
      ae264e3637204a6fb9bb56bc8210ddfd  ... 2906b810c7d4411798c6938adc9daaa5
1                         not received  ...                     not received
3                            completed  ...                     not received
5                         not received  ...                           viewed
8                         not received  ...                        completed
12                        not received  ...                     not received
                               ...  ...                              ...
16995                     not received  ...                     not received
16996                     not received  ...                     not received
16997                     not received  ...                     not received
16998                        completed  ...                     not received
16999                     not received  ...                     not received
```

There are 10 columns were I apply the `value_counts()` method on and get the percentages of the values.

I do it like this:

```
overall = profile[relevant_columns].apply(lambda x: round(pd.Series.value_counts(x) / len(x), 4)* 100)
overall
```

Result:

```
              ae264e3637204a6fb9bb56bc8210ddfd  ...  2906b810c7d4411798c6938adc9daaa5
completed                                21.22  ...                             22.82
not received                             62.47  ...                             63.04
unresponsive                              1.59  ...                              9.29
viewed                                   14.73  ...                              4.86
```

Expected output:

```
              ae264e3637204a6fb9bb56bc8210ddfd  ...  2906b810c7d4411798c6938adc9daaa5
completed                                56.52  ...                             61.82
unresponsive                              4.23  ...                              25.12
viewed                                   39.23  ...                              13.14
```

However, I do not want the percentages of "not received" in my results. I know I could remove the values from each column in  a loop and then apply `table_counts()` to the column, but it would be much better to keep the `apply` workflow over multiple columns in a one-liner. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: kindly provide a minimal, complete, dataframe with your expected output

Comment: Though you have received some answers, your question is incomplete. I guess this maybe of help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The reason why this is not truly reproducible, is because you are sharing the first 5 rows and last 5 rows of data, but your expected output is based on the the entire dataframe. That's why it is better to make the output reproducible based on the input data in your question. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's `mask` the `not received` values in `relevant_columns`, then apply `pd.value_counts` with `normalize=True` to count proportion of unique values per column:

```
profile[relevant_columns].mask(lambda x: x.eq('not received'))\
       .apply(pd.value_counts, normalize=True).mul(100).round(4)
```

---

```
           ae264e3637204a6fb9bb56bc8210ddfd  2906b810c7d4411798c6938adc9daaa5
completed                             100.0                              50.0
viewed                                  NaN                              50.0
```

Comment: thank you, that is my favorite solution, thank you also to all others effort. Learned a lot from that solution :)

Comment: @DataMastery All the solutions are good..If you find them helpful please consider upvoting other solutions too :)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can try [`stacking`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the relevant columns and then use a [`callable`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-callable) to filter out necessary rows, then group on `level=1`(*column names*) and get `value_counts` with `normalize=True` which returns a percentage, then round it and multiply by 100.

```
overall = (profile[relevant_columns].stack().
         loc[lambda x: x!='not received'].
groupby(level=1).value_counts(normalize=True).round(4).mul(100).unstack(0))
```

---

Example based on your input and related output is as below:

```
print(df,'\n') #df is profile[relevant_columns]
print(df.stack().loc[lambda x: x!='not received']
.groupby(level=1).value_counts(normalize=True).round(4).mul(100).unstack(0))
```

---

```
      ae264e3637204a6fb9bb56bc8210ddfd 2906b810c7d4411798c6938adc9daaa5
1                         not received                     not received
3                            completed                     not received
5                         not received                           viewed
8                         not received                        completed
12                        not received                     not received
16995                     not received                     not received
16996                     not received                     not received
16997                     not received                     not received
16998                        completed                     not received
16999                     not received                     not received 

           2906b810c7d4411798c6938adc9daaa5  ae264e3637204a6fb9bb56bc8210ddfd
completed                              50.0                             100.0
viewed                                 50.0                               NaN
```

Side note: If you want to retain the exact column ordering , use `reindex` at the end:

```
overall = (profile[relevant_columns].stack().loc[lambda x: x!='not received'].
groupby(level=1).value_counts(normalize=True)
.round(4).mul(100).unstack(0).reindex(columns=df.columns))

           ae264e3637204a6fb9bb56bc8210ddfd  2906b810c7d4411798c6938adc9daaa5
completed                             100.0                              50.0
viewed                                  NaN                              50.0
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to loop through the columns. Yes, you are looping through columns, but I am also avoiding `lambda x` with my method. Then, just `concat` the list of Series' `s` together after appending each individual new series to a list:

```
s = []
for col in [*profile.columns]:
    (s.append(round(profile.loc[profile[col] != 'not received',[col]]
                           .value_counts(normalize=True)*100, 4)))
df = pd.concat(s, axis=1, keys=relevant_columns)
df
Out[1]: 
           ae264e3637204a6fb9bb56bc8210ddfd  2906b810c7d4411798c6938adc9daaa5
completed                             100.0                              50.0
viewed                                  NaN                              50.0
```